# How to enable GetAsyncKeyState using char?

Tags: c#, char, hook

Good morning, I would like to "enable" the functions from GetAsyncKeyState from a button that is a char
ps. I am making a AutoClicker for game. (sorry for  bad English xd)

example:

````
private void siticoneButton5_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == 27)
            {
                siticoneButton5.Text = "Zbinduj";
                keyRegisteringBool = false;
            }
            if (keyRegisteringBool)
            {
                siticoneButton5.Text = "Bind: " + e.KeyChar.ToString();
                char bind = e.KeyChar;

                keyRegisteringBool = false;
            }
        }
    
//here i have a void with a function


            int min = Convert.ToInt32(materialSingleLineTextField1.Text);
            int max = Convert.ToInt32(materialSingleLineTextField2.Text);

            Random rand = new Random();
            int cps = rand.Next(min, max);

            while (true)
            {                        
                if (GetAsyncKeyState() < 0) //here I want to start this by key down a char.
                {
                    bot.Mouse.LeftButtonClick();
                    Thread.Sleep(1000 / cps);
                }
            }
    ```
````

Thanks in advace

Comment: It's unclear what the question is. Are you having a problem? Please elaborate

Comment: I mean, I have no problem and I don't know how to do a given thing.
it just wants the button in char "bind" to be used in getasynckeystate.